# Does Azure charge for incoming traffic which is blocked by Network Security Group (NSG) firewall rules?

Tags: azure, azure-nsg

Azure charges for incoming traffic to the instance.  However, does Azure also charge for incoming traffic which is blocked by relevant Network Security Group (NSG) firewall rules, which does not reach the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You are not charged for the incoming traffic which is blocked by the Network Security Groups. As the metering starts after passing the ACL layer.